# Tips formatting dictionary with sub-dictionaries into a table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a project for a class that essentially lets the user enter strings and then tag them to make a chart. For example, the user would enter tag categories like colors, size, and texture. Then those categories have subcategories like red, yellow blue. Then they enter item names to sort them into the subcategory for each category. Below is an example of what I mean.

```
rockdictionary = {
'colors' : {
    'red' : ['thing1', 'thing 4'],
    'blue' : ['thing 2', 'thing 3'],
    'yellow' :['thing 5']
    },
'texture': {
    'smooth' : ['thing 5', 'thing 3'],
    'rough' : ['thing1'],
    'bumpy' :['thing4', 'thing 2']},
'size' : {
    'small' : ['thing 2', 'thing 4', 'thing 3'] ,
    'medium': [],
    'large':['thing 1', 'thing 5']
    }
}
```

I figured out how to get a dictionary that looks like the example, but I can't figure out how to format it into a chart like the one below

| item | color | size | texture |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Thing1 | red | small | smooth |
| Thing2 | blue | big | bumpy |

This is what I've got so far:

```
userwidth = int(input('How wide would you like your columns to be? '))
    for key  in categories:
        tableformat1 = '{header:>{width}}'.format(header=key, width=userwidth)
        tableformat2 = '{header:>{width}}'.format(header=key, width=(userwidth*2))
        categorylist = list(categories)
        if key != categorylist[-1]:
            print(tableformat1.format(header=key), end = '|')
        elif key == categorylist[0]:
            print(tableformat2.format(header=key, width=userwidth))
        else:
            print(tableformat1.format(header=key))
            print('-' * (len(categories) * userwidth))
    for name in itemnames:
        column1format = '{item:{width}}'.format(item=name, width=userwidth)
        print(column1format.format(item=name, end = '|'))
        print('-' * userwidth)
```

That gives me:

A| B| C

---

3

---

I'm honestly not really sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. For the full code see here: https://pastebin.com/WSKcDEvx

Answer (score 1):

Restructuring the data in a 2-level dict : `[thing_name][category] = value` and some pandas to get a nice output

```
{
    "thing 1": {"colors": "red","texture": "rough","size": "large"},
    "thing 4": {"colors": "red","texture": "bumpy","size": "small"},
    ...
}
```

```
import pandas as pd

rockdictionary = {
    'colors': {'red': ['thing 1', 'thing 4'], 'blue': ['thing 2', 'thing 3'], 'yellow': ['thing 5']},
    'texture': {'smooth': ['thing 5', 'thing 3'], 'rough': ['thing 1'], 'bumpy': ['thing 4', 'thing 2']},
    'size': {'small': ['thing 2', 'thing 4', 'thing 3'], 'medium': [], 'large': ['thing 1', 'thing 5']}
}

items = defaultdict(dict)
for category, others in rockdictionary.items():
    for value, things in others.items():
        for thing in things:
            items[thing][category] = value

df = pd.DataFrame(items).T.fillna("").sort_index()
print(df)
print(df.to_markdown())
```

```
         colors texture   size
thing 1     red   rough  large
thing 2    blue   bumpy  small
thing 3    blue  smooth  small
thing 4     red   bumpy  small
thing 5  yellow  smooth  large
```

|  | colors | texture | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| thing 1 | red | rough | large |
| thing 2 | blue | bumpy | small |
| thing 3 | blue | smooth | small |
| thing 4 | red | bumpy | small |
| thing 5 | yellow | smooth | large |

Comment: Is there a way to do it without pandas? I'm supposed to stick to modules in the standard library

Comment: @Amabilia iterate the dict and print